# ¿Cómo redimensionar un texto de un H1?

Tags: html, css, funciones

Tengo un H1 con las dimensiones 220 x 22.

Les estoy pasando por PHP una cadena de texto que cambia de tamaño. Uso `font-size` para darle el tamaño al texto, pero la cadena de texto como varía,
en unos se acomoda bien, en otros se mira pequeño y en otros se pasa hasta el punto que genera salto de línea.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías probar añadiendo **font-stretch: condensed**

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que conozcas cómo elaborar una pregunta que sea bien recibida por la comunidad. Muéstranos el código para que sea mas fácil ayudarte.

Answer (score 3):

No se como lo tienes tú, pero me imagino que es una lista. Fuera lo que fuera esta es la lógica:

Pero antes una observación: En el siguiente ejemplo utilizo elementos `<span>`en lugar de tus `<h1>` Normalmente a los `<h1>` los utilizo uno por página.

Estoy envolviendo el texto en un elemento `<span>` que tiene *muy importante* `white-space: nowrap;`. De esta manera voy a calcular la anchura del elemento `<span>` que es también la anchura del texto.

Utilizando un bucle while digo: mientras que la anchura del span es más grande de lo que necesito (160) reduce el tamaño de fuente (fontSize --);

Espero que sea útil.

```js
let w = 160;// la anchura de los elementos li
let FS = 16;// el tamaño de fuente de la lista

//todos l0s elementos span de la lista 
let spans = document.querySelectorAll("#laLista li span")

spans.forEach(span => {
  let bcr = span.getBoundingClientRect();
  let fontSize = FS;
  if (bcr.width > w) {//si la anchura del texto es más grande que la anchura de la lista
    while (bcr.width > w) {//mientras que la anchura del texto es más grande que la anchura de la lista
      fontSize--;//reduce el tamaño de fuente
      span.style.fontSize = fontSize + "px";//reestablece el valor del font-size para el span
      bcr = span.getBoundingClientRect();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
li {  
  display: block;
  width: 160px;
  height: 2em;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
}

li span{  
  font-size:16px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<ul id="laLista">
  <li><span>ABIGAIL TORRES</span></li>
  <li><span>ADA CRUZ</span></li>
  <li><span id="test">ALBERTO DOMINGUEZ</span></li>
</ul>
```